# Is there a way to generate unique random number using rand and randn in Simevents?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simevents

Is there a way to generate unique random number using rand and randn in Simevents? I need to generate random numbers for entity service time using rand and randn, but it seems like the numbers generated are repeated.
I have tried using rng('shuffle') and rng using algorithms (like rng(1,'philox')) by putting the codes in every servers I have. However, the numbers generated are the same. I have also tried this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/334395-how-to-create-random-seed-to-have-different-results-at-each-simevents-run
Is there a way to generate unique random numbers using rand and randn in Simevents? Thank you.

Comment: Random numbers start from the same seed after startup every time by design, see here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/why-do-random-numbers-repeat-after-startup.html. Running `rng('shuffle');` should avoid this, as documented. Please show a [mcve] if this is not the case, otherwise we cannot see your issue.

Comment: @Wolfie Thank you for your comment! I have tried that but still giving me the same repeating values.